# Add .egg file to Jupyter IPython Notebook on Bluemix

Tags: ipython, ibm-cloud, egg, jupyter-notebook

How can I add the .egg file to my Jupyter IPython Notebook on Bluemix? I see documentation for adding jars for scala notebooks, but nothing for python egg files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a zip file with setup script. Put the zip file in object storage. Download zip using http or curl  from object storage into bluemix notebook environment. Do pip install for zip file.